# Unable to get the major and minor values of an estimote beacon to persist into a database

Tags: estimote

I am trying to build an Enterprise App using ibeacons. I purchased Estimote Beacons Kit and trying to build an Android application to get the ID of each beacon, so that I can persist that ID into a Database and write my own business logic for the application.

Can any one help me out to range the beacons. I done with monitoring beacons and sending a Notification accordingly. Now I want only to range the Beacons and get the ID's. Please help with the code to get the beacon major and minor values so that I can kick start my app from there on-words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Estimote Android SDK](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK) for that. See [quickstart](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK#quick-start-for-beacon-ranging) which is beacon ranging:

```
private BeaconManager beaconManager = new BeaconManager(context);

// Should be invoked in #onCreate.
beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
  @Override public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Ranged beacons: " + beacons);
  }
});

// Should be invoked in #onStart.
beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
  @Override public void onServiceReady() {
    try {
      beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Cannot start ranging", e);
    }
  }
});

// Should be invoked in #onStop.
try {
  beaconManager.stopRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Cannot stop but it does not matter now", e);
}

// When no longer needed. Should be invoked in #onDestroy.
beaconManager.disconnect();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, now its working perfect. Now I want to send some push notifications to my application when I enter near to the beacon, but I want this to be done using Google Cloud Messaging can you please help me in this. And it would be nice if you can send some inputs on GCM part